# Accessing and filtering Java class list elements by id

Tags: java

I have a result of type `User` as follows:

```
List<User> result  = (getting values from db)
```

the properties of class User that I need are:

```
private Integer id,
private String name, 
private List<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

etc.

And Class Books has a field Id to.

Given that I have the user Id, and the books Id. I would like to access the other results inside the array book, for that book id.

So I need to -> give the result variable a specific userId, and access books property for that user, then give a bookId, and access book properties for that book id, in that user. I tried using java streams:

```
List<BooksDetails> userBook = result.stream()
  .filter(user -> user.getId() == 1)
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
  .get(0)
  .getBooks()
  .stream()
  .filter(book -> book.getId() == 2)
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
  .get(0)
  .getBooksDetails();
```

But sometimes I get index out of bound error when accessing get(0) element. And it seems there might be a cleaner solution to this. What approaches can I use to accessing nested properties by giving the associated id's in a list?
OR would I have to convert it to a nested map instead?

Comment: Thank you!!! With findFirst(), I can get it to work, but is there a more optimal approach than nested stream? I'm a bit doubtful about the best practice to do it

Comment: The Books class should probably be called Book instead. Typically object names should be singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do the following:

- filter users for userId == 1
- then flatMap the Books list
- filter those books for bookid == 2
- and then get the book details and store in a list

```
record BooksDetails(){};
record Books(int getId, List<BooksDetails> getBooksDetails){}
record User(int getId, List<Books> getBooks){}
  
List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();
         
Optional<List<BooksDetails>> bd = result.stream()
     .filter(user -> user.getId() == 1)
     .flatMap(b->b.getBooks().stream())
     .filter(book -> book.getId() == 2)
     .findFirst()
     .map(Books::getBooksDetails);
```

**Update**

I have updated my answer to include `records` which shows my understanding of your classes.  Since the ultimate result is based on a book Id, I am presuming that  1) it is unique. and 2) there are no duplicate books in the list.  So this will return an `Optional<List<BooksDetails>>` which contains the list of book details for that `bookId` for the `userId`.  If not book is found, it returns an empty optional.

Also,I replaced the flatMap with a Lambda and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. There is unresolved reference when accessing getBooks. In my original answer .getBooks() is the getter method inside User class for property books, so when streaming the values from UserClass, I can access getBooks().  Is there some missing operation after filter so the property becomes available to flatMap?

Comment: I was going to emend my answer.  It looks like you want to return an optional since the book may not be in the users list.

Comment: Interesting problem for me as I have little experience with FlatMap so I did a little demo and I got it to work like so -   ```List<String> userBook = users.stream().filter(u -> u.getId() == 1) .flatMap(v -> v.getBooks().stream()) .filter(book -> book.getId() == 2) .flatMap(v -> v.getBooksDetails().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());```. Is there a benefit to returning an Optional of a List? If its not present, it will just be an empty list right?

Comment: @dbrewster  In these cases I like using Optionals as it is a good habit to get into.  But you are correct in your assessment.

Comment: Thank you WJS for the explanation and updated solution!!
And thank you @dbrewster for the alternate assessment.
I used orElse(), to return an empty instance of the Books class for when it is not present, as I need to display an empty result.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

> List result  = (getting values from db)

Might be not the answer you expect, but this predicate-filter (for `user.id == 1 and book.id == 2`) & find-first probably could be implemented in a layer before the `result`, as (database/SQL) query.

For example:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u 
JOIN books b ON b.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = 1 AND b.id = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. That comment intends to explain that the variable results already holds all results from the database, I did not want to get in the depth of that side of the implemention

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stream` to filter `list` based on `id`. Then based on `filteredList` is empty or not, you will get your data.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(new Book(1, 1, "details1"), new Book(2, 1, "details2"));
        
        final List<User> users = Arrays.asList(new User(1, "name1", books.stream().filter(b -> b.userId == 1).collect(Collectors.toList())),
            new User(2, "name2", books.stream().filter(b -> b.userId == 2).collect(Collectors.toList())), new User(3, "name3", null));
      
      
        final int userId = 1, bookId = 2;
        
        final Book filteredBook = getFilteredBook(userId, bookId, users);
      
        if (null != filteredBook) {
            // put your logic here
            System.out.println(filteredBook.getDetails());
        }

    }
    
    private static Book getFilteredBook(final int userId, final int bookId, final List<User> users) {
        final User filteredUser = users.stream().filter(u -> u.id == userId).findFirst().orElse(null);
        
        if (null == filteredUser) {
            // log your  appropriate error message here
            System.out.println("No user with id: " + userId);
            
            return null;
        }
        
        
        final List<Book> books = filteredUser.books;
        
        if (null == books || books.isEmpty()) {
            // log your  appropriate error message here
            System.out.println("No books associated with userId: " + userId);
            
            return null;
        }
        
        
        final Book filteredBook = books.stream().filter(b -> b.id == bookId).findFirst().orElse(null);
        
        if (null == filteredBook) {
            // log your  appropriate error message here
            System.out.println("No book with id: " + bookId + " associated with userId: " + userId);
            
            return null;
        }
        
        return filteredBook;
    }
    
    
}

class User {
    public final int id;
    public final String name;
    public final List<Book> books;
    
    public User(int id, String name, List<Book> books) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.books = books;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[id: " + id + ", name: " + name + "]";
    }
}

class Book {
    public final int id;
    public final int userId;
    public final String details;
    
    public Book(int id, int userId, String details) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.details = details;
    }
    
    public String getDetails() {
        return this.details;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[id: " + id + ", userId: " + userId + ", details: " + details + "]";
    }
}
```